# Hosting Windows Forms control inside ASP.NET page - IE only?

Tags: asp.net

I've just found out that there is a possibility to host a Windows Forms control inside ASP.NET page. But I'm wodnering - will it run only in IE or in other browsers, such as Firefox, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by embedding an ActiveX control inside the browser, so I think it only works in IE.

But why would you do this? Instead of embedding a Windows Forms control you could embed a silverlight or flash application and get a solution that works on most browsers and has better support.

Embedding Windows Forms controls has never been very popular and is more of a solution looking for a problem than an actually useful technology. :-)

EDIT:
If you really want to do this [look here](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx) for a very simple example

Comment: Do you know if Silverlight is supported by other browsers than IE?

Comment: silverlight is supported in IE and Firefox on windows and Firefox on Mac. There is also a version called Moonlight that gives silverlight support in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to run ActiveX components in Firefox, but that's about it for Microsoft desktop technologies.

Generally I would steer away from this type of solution for almost all applications.